# Passslot doesn't create passes

Tags: ios, passbook, passslot

I am trying to use the API of Passslot to create new passes in my application. Like the example showed I did the following:

```
[PassSlot start:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleIdentifier"]]];

NSDictionary *values = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            @"John", @"firstName" ,
                            @"Doe", @"lastName",
                            @"2012", @"memberSince", nil];

[PassSlot createPassFromTemplateWithName:@"Member Card" withValues:values
    andRequestInstallation:self completion:^{
    NSLog(@"PassSlot is SO EASY!");
}];
```

The application does not throw any errors, the pass itself is just not created (so also the callback function isn't called). I assume that the start of the PassSlot isn't correct. Does anybody know how to get to the "app key"?
http://www.passslot.com/

Comment: Have you registered on the site?

Comment: I did not register because you can download the API without an account. They also didn't mention you needed to register to be able to use the api (which makes sense given the need for certificates). Thank you for the help!

Comment: I'll create an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to register on the site so that you can get an API key and also upload your own Passkit certificate.